# Height of all elements the same in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I would like to have all my boxes the same height
I used the CSS display: flex and it works fine for the first block but not his child
It works fine on Firefox but not on chrome
I found the row-eq-height class on getbootstrap but it isn't better on chrome

[my page on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFvpH.png)

[my page on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHvmP.png)

I have a div class row-eq-height then a col-md-4 and a panel
The panel height don't want to change

the code :

```
<div class="row-eq-height">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default no-padding server-box">
                <!-- Default panel contents -->
                <div class="panel-heading title-box">Regrowth</div>
                <!-- Table -->
                <table class="table server-table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Adresse IP</th>
                        <td>#</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Joueurs en ligne</th>
                        <td class="progress-bar-wrap">
                            <div>
                                <span style="width: 0%;"></span>
                                  <span class="progress-bar-content">0
                                                    /50</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Statut</th>
                        <td><img src="#" alt="status"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ms/Tps</th>
                        <td class="good-tps">2.8 ms / 20 tps</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="heads-tr">
                        <td class="heads-td">
                            <div class="heads">

                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default no-padding server-box">
                <!-- Default panel contents -->
                <div class="panel-heading title-box">InfinityHard</div>
                <!-- Table -->
                <table class="table server-table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Adresse IP</th>
                        <td>#</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Joueurs en ligne</th>
                        <td class="progress-bar-wrap">
                            <div>
                                <span style="width: 6%;"></span>
                                                <span class="progress-bar-content">3
                                                    /50</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Statut</th>
                        <td><img src="#" alt="status"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ms/Tps</th>
                        <td class="#">7.1 ms / 20 tps</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="heads-tr">
                        <td class="heads-td">
                            <div class="heads">
                                <img src="#" alt="Melkutus" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                     data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" title="Melkutus">
                                <img src="#"
                                     data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom"
                                     title="FortunateTrollz">
                                <img src="#" alt="Asseo" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                     data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" title="Asseo">

                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the css

```
    .row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
}
.panel-container .server-box {
    height: 100%;
}
```

thanks to people who will understand and answer me !

Comment: add align-items:stretch; to the .row-eq-height class or try flex: 1; on the children (.row-eq-height > *)

Comment: Wait a sec. Where are you using the .row-eq-height class? I don't see it anywhere in the HTML

Comment: indeed, i wrote the wrong class, sorry
the <div class="global-box"> is <div class="row-eq-height">

Comment: I tried what you proposed but it still not work
As usual, the col-md-4 div has the row-eq-height div height but the height of the panel in the col-md-4 div doesn't change at all

Comment: Your .panel-container .server-box rule only applies to server-boxes INSIDE a panel-container. If you get rid of the ancestor connector it works: https://jsfiddle.net/jphr3hh2/